# Defining groups within an interval

Tags: stata

In Stata with the following data

```
 ID      Date
 1      1/1/2010
 2      1/1/2010
 3      1/4/2010
 4      1/5/2010
 5      1/8/2010
 6      1/10/2010
 7      1/11/2010
```

I am trying to create a variable `Dummyi` that gives a unique variable to all of the `IDs` that occurred within three days (before or after) of the focal `ID`.

I first wanted to identify the IDs that were within a three day window of a given `ID` and then assign a unique number to all of those.

```
 qui forvalues i = 1/`=_N' {
     gen Dummy`i'
     replace Dummy`i' = `i' if Date <= (Date[`i']-3) & ID == `i' 
 }
```

This approach was getting there but there are missing `ID` values, they are not neatly sequential and this wasn't taking the `IDs` that occurred before into account. Finally, multiple `IDs` fall into two groups (e.g. `ID==5`) and I was not sure how to separate without creating separate `Dummy` variables, which is fine.

Resulting data should look like the following.

```
 ID      Date      Dummy1   Dummy2  Dummy3  Dummy4   Dummy5  Dummy6  Dummy7
 1      1/1/2010     1        1       1        0       0       0       0
 2      1/1/2010     1        1       1        0       0       0       0
 3      1/4/2010     1        1       1        1       0       0       0
 4      1/5/2010     0        0       1        1       1       0       0
 5      1/8/2010     0        0       0        1       1       1       1
 6      1/10/2010    0        0       0        0       1       1       1
 7      1/11/2010    0        0       0        0       1       1       1
```

Comment: Can you post what your resulting data should look like and why? I find the wording confusing.

Comment: @RobertoFerrer good point, all set in edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
clear
set more off

*----- example data -----

input ///
 id str10 date
 1      "1/1/2010" 
 2      "1/1/2010"       
 3      "1/4/2010" 
 4      "1/5/2010"
 5      "1/8/2010"
 6      "1/10/2010"
 7      "1/11/2010"
end

gen date2 = date(date, "MDY")
format %td date2
drop date

list

*----- what you want -----

isid id
levelsof id, local(levid)

forvalues i = 1/`=_N' {
    local lid : word `i' of `levid'
    gen ind`lid' = inrange(date2[`i'], date2 - 3, date2 + 3)
}

list, sep(0)
```

`levelsof` I used in case `id` is some irregular sequence. The indicator variable (you call it *dummy*) is named according to the corresponding `id`.

See `help extended_fcn` if you don't have experience with *extended macro functions* (`local lid : word ...`).